# is it possible to check if statement containing an enum at compile time

Tags: c++, cuda

I am writing a "error-check" function whose only task is to check single if statement. This function is overloaded for 7 different error types, but first let me present my code:

**ErrorCheck.h: (whole file)**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __ERROR_CHECK_H__
#define __ERROR_CHECK_H__
// Header does not #include <***> anything. For obvious reasons.

// The function:
template <typename T>
bool errchk(const T check, const char* file, unsigned int line, const char* from, const char* func);

// How To call it:
#define ERRCHK(_check) \
    errchk(_check, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNC__, #_check)

#endif // !__ERROR_CHECK_H__
```

**ErrorCheck.cpp: (simplified version)**

```
// Include:
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cublas.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <cusolver_common.h>
#include "cusparse.h"
#include "ErrorCheck.h"

// Functions bellow are overloaded 7 times for every error type from headers included above
const char * getErrorName(const Type & error) { /* ... */ };
const char * getErrorString(const Type & error) { /* ... */ };

// The function:
template <typename T, T successValue>
bool errchk(const T check, const char* file, unsigned int line, const char* from, const char* func)
{
    if (check != successValue) {
        // Report Error
        return true; // Error was found.
    }
    return false; // No error.
}

// Instantiations:
template bool errchk <bool            > (const bool             check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template bool errchk <cudaError_t     > (const cudaError_t      check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template bool errchk <cufftResult_t   > (const cufftResult_t    check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template bool errchk <cublasStatus_t  > (const cublasStatus_t   check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template bool errchk <curandStatus_t  > (const curandStatus_t   check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template bool errchk <cusolverStatus_t> (const cusolverStatus_t check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
template bool errchk <cusparseStatus_t> (const cusparseStatus_t check, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * from, const char * func);
```

**Question: #1** 
**Is it possible to optimize if statement inside `bool errchk <***> (***)`**
I know that this function is meant to be called at run time, but if we give it a second thought, we will see that we are comparing two enums. 
And therefore meaby could we force compiler to check every possible outcome of `if` statement, and then just run the right one at run-time?

**Question: #2** 
**Does it even need to be optimized??** 
With the `#include <chrono>` lib I have calculated that this code will take up to 40 nanoseconds when "success" value is detected. And up to 400 milliseconds when "error" value is detected.

Comment: 1) If it has to be checked at runtime, then you can't get rid of the check at compile time; 2) It's just a single if statement, so you wouldn't gain much if it was optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to optimize if statement inside `bool errchk <***> (***)`?

It is possible for the *compiler* in some cases, but not for you. You're writing a function that cannot make compile-time assumptions regarding the value of `check`. The compiler, however, might notice that you call, say `errchk(cudaSuccess, whatever, etc, etc)`; and it can choose to [inline](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions) the function, in which case it can notice the `if (check != successValue)` is always true, and simply optimize away the entire call.

> Does it even need to be optimized??

Probably not. If you have this code in a performance-critical tight loop, you should just take it out of the loop; and if you have it elsewhere, 40 ns are not such a big deal. But - you need to [profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) your code to know what you should be optimizing. Don't waste your time optimizing things that take up just a small fraction of the execution time.

Speaking of profiling, CUDA offers a [profiling facility](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/) which can also be used for host-side code. You could also consider using it via my [C++ish wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/) for the CUDA Runtime API ([here](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/blob/master/src/cuda/api/profiling.h) are the profiling-specific API wrappers).

---

PS: In my opinion, you should probably not be writing an errchk function at all. You're working with C++, remember? Instead of this awful inbreeding of macros and templates - use [exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception); and you'll no longer have to remember to check the return value after every call. Exceptions will also let you distinguish types of errors by their class; to nest errors within errors; to express error information using more than just a single number etc.